# sample code: making mocks in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-testing

I am learning Angular2.
In DI pages, there is sample code for mocking.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

What does it mean

```
let mockService = <HeroService> {getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes }
```

It looks like define `mockService` function from `HeroService` function.

What is `<HeroService>`? Is `<HeroService>` casting?

```
let expectedHeroes = [{name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}]
let mockService = <HeroService> {getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes }

it('should have heroes when HeroListComponent created', () => {
  let hlc = new HeroListComponent(mockService);
  expect(hlc.heroes.length).toEqual(expectedHeroes.length);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to [JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814568/2587435) and to give a little explanation on the reasoning behind the code.

TypeScript uses [Structural Type System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system)<sup>**1**</sup>. What this means is that if it quacks like a duck, then it can be considered a duck (or more precisely, be *compatible* with a duck). Take for example

```
class Duck {
  quack() { }
}

let duck = {
  quack: () => {}
}
```

Since `duck` has a `quack` method, you can pass it to anything that expects a `Duck`, like

```
function doQuack(duck: Duck) {
  duck.quack();
}

doQuack(duck);
```

TypeScript is smart enough to know that the `duck` object literal can be considered a `Duck` even if we never actually create an instance of a `Duck` using `duck = new Duck()`. This is because the structure of `duck` is enough to be *compatible* with the `Duck` type, because it matches the structure; the structure being only a single `quack` method.

If we were to try to type `duck` as `Duck`, and we didn't have the `quack` method, then we would get a compile error.

```
let duck: Duck = {   // compile error
  mooo: () => {}
};

let duck: Duck = {
  quack: () => {}    // OK
}
```

That being said, with your example, the `HeroSerivce` has two methods, one to get all the heroes, and one to get a hero by id.

```
class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Hero[] { .. }
  getHeroById(id: number): Hero { .. }
}
```

And a `HeroComponent` with a constructor that accepts a `HeroService`

```
class HeroComponent {
  constructor(heroService: HeroService) {}
}
```

Now if we try to pass the following

```
let mockService = { getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes }
```

to the `HeroComponent` constructor, we will get a compile error because the `mockService` doesn't match the *structure* of a `HeroService`. It only has the one `getHeroes` method, when the structure actually consists of *two* methods, `getHeroes` and `getHero`.

So to force the compiler to just accept it, we "cast" it to `<HeroService>`.

We could pass the following (without "casting") and it would work, because it matches the structure.

```
let mockService = {
  getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes,
  getHero: (id: number) => null
};
```

---

<sub>**1** - Read more from TypeScript documentation chapter [Type Compatibility](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript and TypeScript, `{a: b}` is an object literal. It defined an object with one property `a` having the value `b`.

So

```
{getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes }
```

is an object with one property named `getHeroes`, whose value is `() => expectedHeroes() => expectedHeroes`. The value is thus a function taking no argument (`()`) and returning the value `expectedHeroes`.

`<HeroService>` is called a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler.