# Angular2 mocking injectable service

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I use Angular 2 Karma-Jasmine.
I have  AService,

```
it("test", () => {
    let x:any = function1('value', aService);
    expect(x).toEqual("value1");
});
```

Now `AService` has `getA()` method, and `function1` used `getA()` method.
I want mock `AService.getA` method?.

Please tell me best ways for mocking `AService` ?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection in your test? please provide a bigger example.

Comment: I havent example deat @Supamiu,I want learn best ways for mocking in angular2-jasmine-karma.
My function1 is static,to whcih passed AServcie,there is no injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `function`'s signature is to accept `AService` type

```
function1(value, service: AService) {}
```

then you need to make sure that the mock is compatible with `AService`. If `AService` only has one method `getA`, then you really only need to do

```
let mockA = {
  getA: () => {
    // mock implementation
  }
}
```

If `AService` has more methods than just the `getA` and you don't want to have to implement that, then you can "cast" the mock to type `AService`.

```
let mock = <AService>{ same as above }
```

Or if the `function1` parameter is not typed as `AService`, then you can really pass anything it.

**See Also**:

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39815342/2587435) which gives an explanation about TypeScript's structural type system

Comment: My AService has other methods too. How to do in that case? Please edit answer for that case.

Comment: Thank you,probably it is a best solution for mocking?

Comment: I don't know about _best_ solution, but I do it all the time.

Comment: Thank you,and last question-my getA() has return type,where it I must place in ?
let mockA = <AService> {
  getA: () => {
    // mock implementation
  }
}

Comment: `getA: (): ReturnType => {}`. Though most of the time TypeScript can figure it out just by what you return in the method body.